# How to make a counter running on a server?

Tags: server, counter

I would like to know how to make a counter that continuously runs on a server and that is accessible by any clients (e.g web browsers) anytime (the counter being running continuously on the server - it means I don't have to connect to the server with the client).
I have no specific request for programming language, just need to know the best way to do it

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Is the counter arbitrary or is it supposed to be tracking something?

Comment: just arbitrary, for example starting from 0 and increasing +1 every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the timer is also independent of anything else, you should be able to use any web framework for it, depending on what you're familiar with. Since I prefer Node.js, I'd just write a simple Express.js website, incrementing the counter using some timing library or some built-in JavaScript function.

Since the timer is also independent of clients, I'd use Socket.IO to emit signals when the timer updates so that the clients see changes in real time.

If this timer is going to run for a longer time, you may want to think about how it will persist if/when the server is shut down.